# Close jquery UI dialog destroy data when closing - error to open two consecutive ui dialog

Tags: jquery, user-interface, dialog

I have a table in which to click on each row opens a dialog ( jquery dialog form) with information about that record. This dialog box has tabs and I have problems when I close the dialog box and then open another record since the prior open registration information on the form is maintained.

For example if I close the dialog box on the tab 2 close and open another this opens into the tab 2

Everything works perfect if when close the dialog use window.location.reload () but would prefer to be able to avoid having to reload the page .

If you use dialog ( "destroy ") or dialog.remove not a new box opens (pop up) when you click and whether use dialog ( empty ) the dialog box is opened but the form is empty.

They know some alternative to remove the data from the previous record ?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide basic code that you have done till now.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove your dialog content by following code.

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
    close: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#dialog" ).html();
    }
});
```